# aws swf - get workflow execution id from within the workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am using Amazon SWF service to automate some recurring tasks.

I am trying to use `signals` to execute some commands on remote machines. After the commands are finished executing, I'd like to send a signal back to the workflow to indicate success or failure.

The question is how can I find the `workflow execution id` programmatically? This is required for the remote machines to send a `signal`.

Thanks

Comment: You have access to the [DecisionContext](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/executioncontext.html#executioncontext.decision) inside of your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/SimpleWorkflow/WorkflowExecution.html, shouldn't

```
your_workflow_execution_variable.run_id
```

get you exactly what you're looking for?